# How to find count of a field based on range of 10 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am given a table of years and names of people, Now I need to find the for each year count of people who comes under between that year and next 10 years. How can this be done? Here the years can be overlapping say 1965-74 and 1972-81 etc.

I tried with

```
select concat(hindi2_MOVIE.year, '-', hindi2_MOVIE.year+10) as `range`,
       count(*) as `number of users`
  from hindi2_MOVIE
 where hindi2_MOVIE.year between hindi2_MOVIE.year and hindi2_MOVIE.year + 10
 group by 1
 order by hindi2_MOVIE.year;
```

but all I get is yearwise count?

Comment: Do you only want this ten years or grouped by the next years (from 1974 to 1983, from 1984 to 1993, etc.) ??

Comment: for any given year, i need to find count of next 10 years.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you but get a count of the table would simply be:
`SELECT count(*) FROM hindi2_MOVIE where year BETWEEN starting_year AND starting_year + 10`

Comment: Ya now I need to find this for every distinct year in my table @Olvathar

Comment: What is to be counted for the 10 years - how many total records or how many unique names of people? Also, what is the column name of the user name field?

Comment: @AgRizzo in my table hindi2_MOVIE I have year column. so for eachdistinct value of year I need to find count(*) between year and year+10

Comment: Sample data would make your request clearer. Assume you have 3 records (year, name) = _{2012,Amrith}{2013,Amrith}{2013,Amrith}_ What would the answer be for 2012-2021? Is it 1 because Amrith repeats, 2 because Amrith is only counted once per year or 3 - counted every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
SELECT per_year.year, SUM(per_year.count) as total_decade
FROM hindi2_MOVIE INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT count(*) as count, year FROM hindi2_MOVIE GROUP BY year) per_year ON hindi2_MOVIE.year >= per_year.year AND hindi2_MOVIE.year < per_year.year + 10
GROUP BY hindi2_MOVIE.year
```

Comment: what is per_year_count ?

Comment: It first takes count for each year and joins each year with the count of itself of the next 9. Grouping by year you'll get all them

Comment: Be careful, with huge data I think this will require a lot of cpu time

Comment: thats fine, but one problem is its not showing the decade 2013-2023 or 2006 - 2015? thought they are futuristic year, it should show theewntriesf orsame i think. any reasons?

Comment: There are no reason for not showing them, do you have any entry for 2013? External group by will restrict only for existing years. With no entries for 2013 it won't show 2013-2023 decade

Answer (score 0):

If you have movies in every year, then try this:

select concat(min(m.year), '-', max(m.year)) as `range`,
       count(*) as `number of users`
from hindi2_MOVIE m
group by floor((m.year / 10)
order by min(m.year);

I made several changes to the query:

- Remove the `where` clause.  It is not doing anything.
- Changed the range calculation to use `min()` and `max()`.  This specifies the actual years in the range.
- Changed the `group by` to divide by 10, and take the floor.  That way, the decades would typically be `2000-2009`, `2010-2019`, and so on.
- Added in a table alias for readability.